# Sharing Google Motion Charts

Tags: r, googlevis

I created a google motion chart through R. When I execute the code, it pops up on a webpage but I can only see it on my computer and can't send it. Any ideas would be helpful.

I can't make it reproducible because it is confidential information but essentially this is what the code looks like:

```
library(googleVis)
M<-gvisMotionChart(df,idvar="Zone",timevar="Date")
plot(M)
```

So I want to be able to email/share the link but can't figure it out.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: create a knitr Rmd with it - https://github.com/mages/googleVis/blob/master/vignettes/Using_googleVis_with_knitr.Rmd - since you can make them self-contained and share the HTML file out, then.

Comment: @hrbrmstr For some reason that didn't work it just made an html file with the js code. A warning message came up stating: Warning message:
In in_dir(opts_knit$get("root.dir") %n% input_dir(), evaluate::evaluate(code,  :
  You changed the working directory to C:/Users/Nicholas/Desktop/Answers (probably via setwd()). It will be restored to C:/Users/Nicholas/Desktop. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
{r results='asis',echo=FALSE}
require(googleVis)
op<-options(gvis.plot.tag="chart")
M=gvisMotionChart(df, idvar = "Zone", timevar = "Date")
plot(M)
```